# How do I consume a COM+ local server from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, com+

I have a web application from a company that has gone out of business.  We're looking to extend the web app a bit with some asp.net functionality.  The web app was written as an ISAPI application in Delphi, and uses COM+ to talk to the SQL Server and handles things like session management and authentication.

So, in order to get the current user and other details, I have to use the undocument COM+ components.  I was able to dig out the type library and auto generated IDL, but at this point i'm lost in creating a .NET proxy class for this.

**Is there a way to autogenerate the .net COM+ proxy either from the .dll itself (extracting the typelib info) or from the IDL?**

Note: These seem to be simple COM style objects hosted in COM+ servers, no subscriptions or transaction monitoring..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(VS.80).aspx) to generate C# proxy classes from your COM library.

```
tlbimp.exe myTest.tlb /out:myTest.dll
```

If you don't have the `tlb` it works also with COM `dlls`. Once the COM wrapper assembly generated you can reference it in your project and use the types inside as you would any other .NET class.

Possible location of `tlbimp.exe` : `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\TlbImp.exe` or use the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks.  Sadly, it's so difficult to google for this information these days.. or maybe my goo-fu is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Run Tlbimp.exe on the type library to generate the .NET interop assembly for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to the references in your project, right clicking, add reference, then browsing to the dll. I think visual studio will generate the Runtime Callable Wrapper for you.